# Mouseup and mousedown not working on ios

Tags: jquery, ios, html, mousedown, mouseup

So I need something like the following, it's basically a 2-dir touchpad that the user touches (and holds the touch) with his finger to move the character a certain way. This works fine on my PC, but it doesn't seem to work when I test it on iOS. The reason being, is probably because there is not mouse, so **mousedown** and **mouseup** don't work. Are there any alternatives? I've tried to use **keydown** and **keyup** but those didn't work either.

Here's my code:

```
var $div = $('#character');

$('#ios-left').mousedown(function(){
   leftTimer = setInterval(function(){
    processWalk('left');
    },100);
}).mouseup(function(){
    $('#character').stop();
    clearInterval(leftTimer);
});
$('#ios-right').mousedown(function(){
        rightTimer = setInterval(function(){
     processWalk('right');
             },100);
}).mouseup(function(){
    $('#character').stop();
    clearInterval(rightTimer);
});
```

Thanks!
(Keep in mind that I need the user to hold the div down with his finger to have the character move and when he releases his finger, the character should stop)

**EDIT:** Link to my question: [JQuery Mouseup on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957080/jquery-mouseup-on-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use very lite weight **[jquery.mouse2touch.min.js](//cdn.rawgit.com/vpanga/MouseEventSimulatorWithTouch/master/src/jquery.mouse2touch.min.js)** plug-in to simulate mouse events for touch events.

Apply mouse event handler behavior to touch events like below `$("#elmentID").mouse2touch()` OR `$(".elment-css-class").mouse2touch()` which will do the job to copy all mouse based functionality to touch.

In your code you can call `mouse2touch()` like below:

```
$('#ios-left').mousedown(function(){
   leftTimer = setInterval(function(){
    processWalk('left');
    },100);
}).mouseup(function(){
    $('#character').stop();
    clearInterval(leftTimer);
}).mouse2touch();

$('#ios-right').mousedown(function(){
        rightTimer = setInterval(function(){
     processWalk('right');
             },100);
}).mouseup(function(){
    $('#character').stop();
    clearInterval(rightTimer);
}).mouse2touch();
```

---

EDIT: For another linked [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957080/jquery-mouseup-on-ios) and here I'm providing same answer.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/gqfesrhw/1/)**

The issue with timer, you should clear-time-interval before move. Your global variable `TimerWalk` with `clearInterval(TimerWalk);` should be useful.

**Here is the code block**

```
$('#ios-left').mousedown(function () {
    clearInterval(TimerWalk);
    TimerWalk = setInterval(function () {
        processWalk('left');
    }, 100);
}).mouseup(function () {
    $div.stop();
    clearInterval(TimerWalk);
}).mouse2touch();

$('#ios-right').mousedown(function () {
    clearInterval(TimerWalk);
    TimerWalk = setInterval(function () {
        processWalk('right');
    }, 100);
}).mouseup(function () {
    $div.stop();
    clearInterval(TimerWalk);
}).mouse2touch();
```

This is only fix for proper movement, you may need to address other issues.

Comment: could you help me with another problem in chat?

Comment: Sure send me chat request?

Comment: I don't have enough rep yet sorry, would you mind posting one?

Comment: I'm glad to help you and you can ask your Question on this wonderful site any time. Lot of professional available on this n/w to help you. All the best! You may drop your question link here to notify me

Comment: Thank you! Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957080/jquery-mouseup-on-ios

Comment: I'll take a look when I've time, may be coming week.