# JQuery Mouseup on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mousedown, mouseup

I've recently added the [jquery.mouse2touch.min.js](http://cdn.rawgit.com/vpanga/jquery.mouse2touch/master/src/jquery.mouse2touch.min.js) plugin to my game, and after testing it out I ran into a problem. My movement system is made up of two divs (one to move the player left and one to move him right), basically when you press and hold the div, the player should move in one direction and when you let go, he should stop. The problem is that if I press down for too long and then let go, the player doesn't stop.

Here's the code that gets him moving:

```
// iControl System
var $div = $('#character');

$('#ios-left').mousedown(function(){
   leftTimer = setInterval(function(){
       processWalk('left');
   },100);
}).mouseup(function(){
    $('#character').stop();
    clearInterval(leftTimer);
}).mouse2touch();

$('#ios-right').mousedown(function(){
    rightTimer = setInterval(function(){
       processWalk('right');
    },100);
}).mouseup(function(){
    $('#character').stop();
    clearInterval(rightTimer);
}).mouse2touch();
```

and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqfesrhw/

Thanks (Also if anyone thinks that this may be a problem with the mouse2touch plugin, I'd be open to other suggestions)

Comment: `.mouse2touch()` call map your mouse events to touch events. That shouldn't do any harm to your functionality. To cross check the behavior, is it working with out the plug-in call? I just checked the behavior with your fiddle in chrome it seems functioning. Be specific on the issue so that you can take right help. On what browser you're testing?

Comment: I'm testing this on Safari on my iPhone. It works fine on my computer with/ or without the plugin, but on the iPhone it does what I said above.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpanga/gqfesrhw/2/)**

The issue with timer, you should clear-time-interval before move. Your global variable `TimerWalk` with `clearInterval(TimerWalk);` should be useful.

**Here is the code block**

```
$('#ios-left').mousedown(function () {
    clearInterval(TimerWalk);
    TimerWalk = setInterval(function () {
        processWalk('left');
    }, 100);
}).mouseup(function () {
    $div.stop();
    clearInterval(TimerWalk);
}).mouse2touch();

$('#ios-right').mousedown(function () {
    clearInterval(TimerWalk);
    TimerWalk = setInterval(function () {
        processWalk('right');
    }, 100);
}).mouseup(function () {
    $div.stop();
    clearInterval(TimerWalk);
}).mouse2touch();
```

This is only fix for proper movement, you may need to address other issues.

Comment: Thanks for replying Venkata,however I'm still stuck with the same problem....The character is still walking on.

Comment: clear the browser cache before running. if problem still persists please let me know with detailed behavior

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help, enjoy the bounty :)

Comment: @NotToBrag Updated mouse2touch plug-in reference link address to new repository and Please mark this as answer :)